# How to get the column and modify its css once I have just added a new row to a bootstrap datatable?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datatables, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap datatable and I need to modify the style in some of the column.

I'm at this point where I have the rowNode but I don't know how to access the column and modify its css.

```
var rowNode = t.row.add( [
                    "<input type='checkbox' id='parent_" + data.workItemID + "' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#child_'" + data.workItemID + "'> </input><label for='parent_" + data.workItemID + "'></label>",
                    "<a href='#' onclick='editWorkItem(" + data.workItemID + ")'><span class='fa fa-pencil'> </span></a><button id='btnDelete' value='delete' type='button' class='btn-link' data-toggle='modal' data-object-id=" +  data.workItemID + " data-object-name=" +  data.workType + " data-target='#deleteNonInstructionalModal'> <i class='fa fa-trash'></i> </button>",
                    data.workItemID,
                    data.workType,
                    "0",
                    data.academicYear,
                    data.workItem,
                    data.description,
                    "<a href='#' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='left' title='" +  data.orgHierarchy + "'>" + data.orgLevel + "</a>"
                ] ).draw( false ).node();
```

I want to make the style="display: none;" to the column where I have the data.workItemID.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(rowNode).find('td:eq(2)').hide();
```

or

```
$(rowNode).find('td:eq(2)').css('display', 'none');
```

**BUT** if you use `display:none` it will mess up the DataTable view.

you will be better off using `visibility:hidden`

```
$(rowNode).find('td:eq(2)').css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone) to know about difference between display:none and visibility:hidden

Answer (score 0):

You hide the column with

```
t.column(2).visible(false);
```

You cannot set the visibility or display status for individual cells.